# How to convert "12/08/16" to date format and compare in VBA?

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I have following code which was working perfectly before but it doesn't work now.

Following is code which convert string date to date and compare with today's date.
Code:

```
Dim fileDate1 As Date
fileDate1 = CDate("12/08/16")   'dd/mm/yy'
If Format(fileDate1, "yyyymmdd") < Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") Then
    //delete file because date changed
    KillFileOnMac XMLFilePath
End If
```

Can anybody suggest me what I am missing here?

Comment: Where does the error occur? Don't you mean Now with Date?

Comment: @Wernerson I mean it was working in my older system. I have change the system now. I don't know whether it is related or OS. But above code doesn't work. The variable `fileDate1` is blank.

Comment: As Wernerson asks where does the error occur?

Comment: So does your condition fail or does an error occur ( if yes, what error) and have you changed from Windows to OSX or vice versa?

Comment: I'm guessing someone has changed the system settings do that CDate does no longer see its arguments as dd/mm/yy. On my system that line sets fileDate1 back in 2012.

Comment: @DragonSamu I don't get error but I don't get any data while converting using CDate. Anyways, I have handle this in MacScript. Now MacScript is handling date comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nanji, the comment on the second row is dubious, on my system that row sets fileDate1 back in year 2012, august 16. It would be much safer to use instead:

```
fileDate1 = DateSerial(2016, 8, 12)
```

(for clarity, you might also consider getting rid of the calls to "format", just compare the dates directly: `If fileDate1 < Date Then...` )

Comment: Thank you. I have handled this in MacScript. Now MacScript is handling date comparison. I can use your solution also but for that I must populate some parameter. I think the alternate way I have used MacScript is looks better because it handle all date format.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were expecting that cDate("12/08/16") would equal August 12, 2016. The date is actually December 8, 2016.

We can tell by:

```
Dim fileDate1 As Date
fileDate1 = CDate("12/06/16")
MsgBox Format(fileDate1, "yyyymmdd")
```

This shows 20161206.

So, it looks like your date string input is the problem. Once you have that worked out, as Mats Lind suggested, you don't need to format dates to compare them. Here's how I would handle it :

```
Dim fileDate1 As Date
fileDate1 = CDate("12/08/16")

If fileDate1 < DateValue(Now) Then

    MsgBox "I shall kill the file because the date changed"
    KillFileOnMac XMLFilePath
Else
    MsgBox "The file date is today or newer "

End If
```

I use dateValue(Now) because it works cross-platform. I shy away from MacScript because I don't expect it will be supported forever. 
Hope this helps.